# Iterating through an array and replacing data within a template

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an XML document with "tags" that are replaced based on data within an array.  There are two types of tags, one is a parent tag to define a set, another is simply a tag that is replaced by a value.  Here's an example of the data used to build and fill in the template:

```
$array  = array(
 'name'     => 'name',
 'city' =>  'city',
 'addresses'    =>  array(
    array(
     'street'   => '123',
     'city' =>  'main'
    ),
    array(
     'street'   => '123',
     'city' =>  'main'
     'phone'    =>  array(
        array(  
        'home'  =>  '123456',                                                                 'work'    =>  '1234567'
        )
```

Here is an example template:

```
        <name>%name%</name>
        <city>%city%</city>
        %%addresses%%
            <street>%street%</street>
            <city>%city%</city>
            %%phone%%
                <home>%%home%%</home>
                <work>%%work%%</work>
            %%/phone%%
        %%/addresses%%
```

The key values of the array, match the tags within the template.  If the key is an array itself, then it loops through the data contained within that key's tag (%%).

I've tried doing a recursive function but it only seems to work one level deep.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: So you structured an XML-like template var-tree into an XML file? Is there any chance to change the template? And in which direction should this be applied? Should the values from the array filled into the template or should the template tell which values should be picked from the array?

Comment: The template has no format, can be anything.

Comment: So it's okay to answer your question and change the template format?

Comment: I guess, I mean it would need to work with this template as well

Comment: I suggest you should use a simple existing template language that just works, like [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), there are plenty much others. I know that mustache supports looping over arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out, may be a little overkill, this is just for a small part of a larger app

Comment: @harkre - Actually, Mustache seems to do the job perfectly! Can you answer this and I'll choose you?

Comment: Added an answer :) And good to read it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use an existing simple template language that "just works"<sup>tm</sup>, like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) (there are plenty much others). I know that Mustache supports looping over arrays, used it, does the job, easy to integrate. Available for many languages.